# How to you change the text in the cells of a calculated field column in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I have the following code in the 'edit' window:

```
IF [Location_]='Paradise, Nevada, U.S'

THEN 'Las Vegas, Nevada, U.S.'

ELSEIF [Location_]='Paradise, Nevada, U.S.'

THEN 'Las Vegas, Nevada, U.S.'

ELSE [Location_]

END
```

And below I am told 'The calculation is valid'. But no changes are made and I just end up with a column identical to 'Location_'

Many thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using Groups for this type of task?  I suppose you might not be able to create a group from the web editor?

Comment: I did attempt the code you were using and it appears to work for me.  Are you able to include some screenshots of the data and the edit window?  You might want TRIM your location as well.  There could be white space at the beginning or end of the location.

Comment: Agreed with Uxonith, if you aren't seeing any change of your test text to Las Vegas, then the value you are testing in your IF doesn't exist that way. You can also include `UPPER()` `IF UPPER([Location_] = 'PARADISE, NEVADA, U.S.'`

Comment: I have resolved the issue, it was indeed a case of whitespace at the end of the location. Many thanks for both your help